# In Highcharts, how do I make my piechart label text the same color as the pie part?

Tags: highcharts, pie-chart

I am using the latest version (9.3.2) of Highcharts as for now.

And I would like to know whether it is possible to make the text color of the two labels the same as the related pie has.

I didn't set any color in the settings and I believe it's a default color value created by highcharts itself.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dataLabels.formatter` function and define color for the data label as the same as for the point.

```
    series: [{
        ...,
        dataLabels: {
            formatter: function() {
                const point = this.point;
                return '<span style="color: ' + point.color + '">' +
                    point.name + ': ' + point.y + '%</span>';
            }
        }
    }]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qnjevg7c/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.pie.dataLabels.formatter